# Wordpress posts - attached images

Tags: jquery, attachment, wordpress, nivo-slider

Is there any way to display all attached images to a certain post? I am using the Nivo Slider jQuery plugin and looking for a smart way to add images to it. The best would be just to create a post and then attach the images I want in the slider. So what I need is some kind of loop that echoes all the attached images from a certain post.

Comment: Ah, new to this forum. Didn't know I was supposed to mark the right answers. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $post;
$attachements = query_posts(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, // or static id, i.e. 7
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
foreach($attachements as $attachment){
    $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
    echo $thumbimg;
}
```

[**More.**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_all_attachments)

Comment: Did you use the same code, may be you have some typos, mistakenly you could have done something wrong in your code.

Comment: [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622624/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-double-arrow-php).